# LG Gram laptop keyboard backlight refuses to work

Tags: kernel, keyboard, hardware, backlight

Title pretty much. I've tried reloading the kernel module, I've tried xset led 3, I've tried using brightnessctl, nothing works. It's not a hardware issue, since in windows 10 it works just fine, and sometimes on bootup it'll turn on for a few seconds and then turn off again before booting into Ubuntu. Any help would be appreciated. I'm running Ubuntu 23.04, kernel version 6.2.0-23-generic (64bit), and my laptop's model number is 14T90N.

Comment: I have zero problems with an LG 17" and an LG 16". Everything works out of the box. Same kernel.  Is your ACPI active or did you disable it? `ls /sys/class/backlight/` should have `intel_backlight`. Does `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight` exist?  "It's not a hardware issue" it is an BIOS+ACPI versus kernel issue.  Try to boot with one of these `acpi_backlight=video`,  `acpi_backlight=vendor`, 
`acpi_backlight=native`

Comment: intel_backlight is present in the backlight class. Trying the 3 acpi_backlight commands in startup options in grub didn't fix it.